# Download WordPress.com theme: how?

Tags: themes

I like [this theme](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/fresh-and-clean/).

But I don't want it to use with a wordpress.com blog but download it to use with my WordPress site at my own domain.

But I can't find a download link. Is it possible?

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65056/how-to-get-themes-from-wordpress-com-per-svn for detailed instructions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For custom installation you should search for the theme on [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) site.

> <s>The Wordpress.com hosts themes that are available for use only on wordpress.com blogs and they do not provide download link there.</s>
>   
>  <sub>- See [@markratledge's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/68068/17968) below.</sub>

Here's the link to download that theme - http://www.wpexplorer.com/fresh-clean-wordpress-theme-by-wpexplorer

Comment: "The Wordpress.com hosts themes that are available for use only on wordpress.com blogs and they do not provide download link there." Wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Wordpress.com themes are available to download from .com either manually or with an svn client. Go to http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/ to browse them.

Grab the files with a text editor, or use an svn client to download the theme folder. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients for a client for your OS.

***10/12/2012 Update:*** there are two svn areas for .com themes; see Otto's comment below. Some tweaks may be necessary for themes downloaded from the .com repositories to get them to fully function on self-hosted WP sites.

Comment: Actually, those are themes that are in the WordPress.org plugin directory. They're not the WordPress.com themes, exactly. The wordpress.com themes can be found here: https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/ Note that they may have code specific to wordpress.com in them, and thus might need tweaking to work on self-hosted setups. If the main Theme directory has a version of the same theme, it would be better to use that one than to use the wordpress.com version.

Comment: Thanks, Otto; good points. I didn't know about the other repository you linked. I wonder why those theme are in the plugin directory? Legacy? A theme called "fresh and clean" - that waanders is looking for - is at the URL you added.

Comment: It's probably the same theme in both locations. Using the .org version is preferable on self-hosted sites, but not all themes on .com are in the .org repo.

Answer (score 1):

SVN is quite troublesome, I know, but there's no need for SVN anymore. You can easily search and download for themes here:

http://design311.com/wpthemes/

Comment: To quickly jump to a named one, you can go to `http://design311.com/wpthemes/theme/<name_of_theme>`