# How to get themes from wordpress.com per SVN?

Tags: themes

I'm running wordpress on my own host and would like to install the Ideation and Intent theme. I couldn't, however, find a place to download it from, nor can I search for it on my Wordpress dashboard under Appearance -> Themes.

The best I could find was this svn url: https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/ideation-and-intent/

Does anyone know how I can get the theme?

http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/ideation-and-intent/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a theme or plugin for which you have just the SVN URL you need three steps:

1. Install a SVN client. For Windows you might take [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/).
2. Create an empty directory where you need the code.
3. Right click in that directory and use the **Checkout** command to download the code.

   [image]

After you have clicked **OK** all the files are fetched from the remote repository.

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing an "svn co" and zipping the file before uploading it to the site.

Comment: Ideally, you'd actually want to do an `svn export` instead, so as to get a copy of the theme without the associated .svn directories. A checkout is a working copy with metadata, an export is just a copy of the files.

Comment: There's no need for SVN anymore, check this out: http://design311.com/wpthemes

Comment: @user2019515 Always use the latest version from the original source. I wouldn't trust third party services.

Comment: That's my website, which I made for easy downloading for myself. So I trust it, but I understand your concerns.